# I don't have AirPlayFeature

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have just installed new xcode with sdk 4.3b because I need 'airPlay' feature in my current project which is based on sdk 4.2. But I open my project and type my MPMoviePlayerController object....

```
mpObject.???
```

... but here I don't have allowAirPlay property. But when I start new project and create movie player I have that property, but don't have in my old project, what should I setup to have this?

Comment: This concerns a feature still under NDA. You should ask your question on Apple's private dev forum: https://devforums.apple.com/community/iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 4.3 beta (as with all iOS betas) is under NDA and not something you're supposed to discuss in public. General advice would be not necessarily to trust Xcode's autocompletion (it's not infallible).

Comment: This is not SDK based question. SDK works when I create new project. The problem is when I open my old project in preferences I have changes baseSdk to 4.3 and I remove and import MediaPlayer framework and in MPMoviePlayer class there is allowAirPlay proerly but when I type it in code it doesn't work. I assume that I didn't change something I heve never until now change sdk version in project.

Comment: We are discussing a property on a class that isn't defined in the 4.2 API, which you are alleging (to keep the question open) to be present in the 4.3 API. You're therefore discussing something that, if true, is currently under NDA.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably linking to the old 4.2 MediaPlayer Framework. Try Deleting the framework from project and adding it again.

Comment: I have tried everythin. I solve it by creating new project based on new sdk and copy my files in it. But i still don't know how to implement airplay because i don;t use standard movie player controls instead i have overlay view over player with custom cintrols (play,stop, airplay etc) but stll i don't know how to implement custom button airplay :(